# JavaScript - short way of declaring an associative array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Is there a short way of declaring an associative array like in PHP?

```
$myArray = array('a' => 'b'); // PHP Way
```

In JavaScript I'd do it this way:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray['a'] = 'b';
```

<s>I'm not looking for JavaScript objects.</s>

Comment: *"I'm not looking for JavaScript objects."* Why not? Is there a particular reason you want non numeric properties on an Array?

Comment: A friend asked about a short way and I didn't find any. I just want to know wether there is a short way or not.

Comment: Well if you really want an Array, and not a plain Object, then no, there isn't anything aside from creating a helper function and passing it an Object to populate the Array

Comment: @dotweb: Have fun avoiding objects when working with JavaScript. :)

Comment: This has been cleared up time and again. Just look at the related posts on the right.

Comment: So you *do* want a plain JavaScript object???

Comment: Lol, everything in Javascript inherits from `object`

Comment: Well, not primitives, but they're implicitly converted to their Object inherited wrappers when needed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays. In your example, you declare `myArray` as array but then you assign an object to it. So your code is not different from this:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject['a'] = 'b';
```

*Update:* A little correction. Actually, the original code does not destroy the array. It just appends a regular property to it. That's possible because JavaScript arrays are a subset of JavaScript objects.

Comment: which is the same as `myObject.a = 'b';`, since you can use dot notation as long as the property name is a valid JS variable name, so you could not use dot notation for `myObject['no dot!'] = 'b'`.

Comment: Nonsense. Of course javascript has associative arrays. For all intents and purposes thats what a Javascript Object *IS*. How it works under the hood is neither here nor there.

Comment: @RichardRiley - A JavaScript object is [an unordered collection of properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). The concept of *order* is possibly the key point of arrays.

Comment: This is not 100% correctly, and the two are **not** the same. You cannot iterate, in order, on an Object since it does not work like an Array, which was designed to be iterate-able. The question is how to create such an array in a non-repeatable manner.

Answer (score 33):

Declare an object like this:

```
var myArray = {"a": "b", "c": "d"};
```

... and then refer to each item like this:

```
var somethingElse = myArray["a"]; //Sets "somethingElse" to "b".
```

As @Chris and @Marc mention in the comments: in JavaScript, objects ARE associative arrays, and vice versa, they just refer to two different ways of doing the same thing. For Example...

```
var somethingElse = myArray["a"];
var anotherVariable = myArray.a;
```

... do the same thing.

Comment: You should mention there is no such thing as associative arrays in javascript.

Comment: Wrong. In javascript, all arrays are associative arrays.

Comment: @Chris - As far as I was aware, associative arrays and objects are basically the same thing in JavaScript. They're just different ways of referring to the same thing. e.g. `myArray["a"]` vs `myArray.a`

Answer (score 9):

> I'm not looking for JavaScript objects.

There are no "associative arrays" in JavaScript, just objects comprised of property names and values which can be treated as such. So, what you are looking for is in fact objects. In fact, this example from your question is working with an object:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray['a'] = 'b';
alert(typeof myArray); // 'object'
```

You initially construct the object using the array literal syntax:

```
var myArray = [];
```

which means you have created an object which inherits from `Array.prototype`. So essentially, you are dealing with an object which has been augmented with the methods stored in `Array.prototype`.

To check that `myArray` is actually an array (well, I would say JavaScript arrays are pseudo-arrays), you can check its constructor:

```
alert(typeof myArray === 'object' && myArray.constructor === Array);
```

There's a better way which will also identify arrays constructed in different windows and frames:

```
alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(myArray) === '[object Array]');
```

You can also use `instanceOf`:

```
alert(myArray instanceof Array);
```

or `Array.isArray`:

```
alert(Array.isArray(myArray));
```

Comment: *"The only way to tell..."* You're forgetting about `[] instanceof Array`, `Object.prototype.toString.call( [] )` and `Array.isArray( [] )`. ;o)

Answer (score 6):

In javascript, associative arrays, keyed collections, hashes, ... whatever you want to call them, are not a special type. All the following are good.

```
a = {}
a[3] = 15
a.b = "c"
a['def'] = 'something'
```

This code produces a single valid object with the properties you would expect.  All of them. You can combine a conventionally indexed array and an associative array in one object.

As to declaring a whole bunch at once, the usual syntax is:

```
a = {
    'key1' : 'val1',
    'key2' : val2,
    key3 : val3,
    key4 : "val4"
}
```